# Proving $\| g^{-1}-f^{-1}\|\leq 2\|{f^{-1}}\|^2\|g-f\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $f,g\in L(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and let $f^{-1},g^{-1}\in L(Y,X)$.

How to prove that 
$$\| g^{-1}-f^{-1}\|\leq 2\|{f^{-1}}\|^2\|g-f\|$$  if 
$\|g-f\|\leq\frac{1}{2\| f^{-1}\| }$?

Comment: Are you sure the inequalities are correct? It looks a bit strange to me. Either way the identity $g^{-1} - f^{-1} = g^{-1}(f-g)f^{-1}$ might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, they are correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuously invertible operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271840/continuously-invertible-operators) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5C%7C%20g%5E%7B-1%7D-f%5E%7B-1%7D%5C%7C%5Cleq%202%5C%7C%7Bf%5E%7B-1%7D%7D%5C%7C%5E2%5C%7Cg-f%5C%7C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2):

$\|gf^{-1}-I\| =\|(g-f)f^{-1}\|\leq \frac 1  2$. The series $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (I-gf^{-1})^{k}$ converges to $(gf^{-1})^{-1}=fg^{-1}$. Hence $\|fg^{-1}\| \leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac 1 {2^{k}}=2$. It follows that $\|g^{-1}\| \leq 2\|f^{-1}\|$. Now by the identity in the comment above by Alex we get $\|g^{-1}-f^{-1}\| \leq \|g^{-1}\|\|f^{-1}\||\|g-f\|\leq 2\|f^{-1}\|^{2}|\|g-f\|$.

Comment: I found an identical question (with answers) in less than a minute. How long did you search?